# List MAX and MIN in the same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to list the county with the highest poverty rate and that with the lowest poverty rate under the same column next to the State each belongs to. Like this:

```
+----------+--------+--------------+
| State    | County | Poverty Rate |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| Delaware | AB     | 0.1234       |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| Delaware | CD     | 0.6789       |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| Virginia | EF     | 0.1357       |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| Virginia | GH     | 0.4680       |
+----------+--------+--------------+
```

But I only got as far as showing three columns: State, Highest Poverty Rate, Lowest Poverty Rate, with the code below:

```
;WITH poverty_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        state
        ,County
        ,AVG(pctPoor)    AS 'Poverty'
    FROM [SQLBook].[dbo].[ZipCensus]
    WHERE County IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY County, state
)
SELECT
    CASE state
        WHEN '10' THEN 'Delaware'
        WHEN '51' THEN 'Virginia'
        ELSE 'Others'
    END                     AS State
    ,MAX(Poverty)           AS 'Highest Poverty Rate'
    ,MIN(Poverty)           AS 'Lowest Poverty Rate'
FROM poverty_CTE
WHERE state IN (10, 51)
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY State
```

This is the result:

```
+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| State      | Highest Poverty Rate | Lowest Poverty Rate |
+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| Delaware   | 0.6789               | 0.1234              |
+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| Washington | 0.4680               | 0.1357              |
+------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want without complicated subqueries?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sample table data (and the expected result) provided in proper columns would be much easier to read.

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [SQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to your question... with subqueries:

```sql
create table dbo.ZipCensus (
  State int,
  County varchar(20),
  pctPoor float
);

insert dbo.ZipCensus (State, County, pctPoor) values
  (10, 'AB', 0.1234),
  (10, 'CD', 0.6789),
  (51, 'EF', 0.1357),
  (51, 'GH', 0.4680);

select State, County, [Poverty Rate]
from (
  select
    S.State,
    County,
    [Poverty Rate],
    LeastPoor = row_number() over (partition by P.State order by [Poverty Rate] asc, County asc),
    MostPoor = row_number() over (partition by P.State order by [Poverty Rate] desc, County asc)
  from (
    select State, County, avg(pctPoor) as [Poverty Rate]
    from dbo.ZipCensus
    where State in (10, 51)
    group by State, County
  ) P
  join (values
    (10, 'Delaware'),
    (51, 'Virginia')
  ) S (StateID, State) on S.StateID=P.State
) R
where LeastPoor=1 or MostPoor=1
order by State, [Poverty Rate]
```

Which yields the result:

```
State   County  Poverty Rate
Delaware    AB  0.1234
Delaware    CD  0.6789
Virginia    EF  0.1357
Virginia    GH  0.468
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think ROW_NUMBER is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT state_name, county, poverty_rate
FROM (SELECT (CASE state WHEN '10' THEN 'Delaware' WHEN '51' THEN 'Virginia' END) as state_name,
             County, AVG(pctPoor) as poverty_rate,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY AVG(pctPoor) ASC) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY AVG(pctPoor) DESC) as seqnum_desc
      FROM [SQLBook].[dbo].[ZipCensus]
      WHERE County IS NOT NULL AND state IN ('10', '51')
      GROUP BY County, state
     ) s
WHERE 1 IN (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
ORDER BY state_name, poverty_rate;
```

Note that the subquery is doing a lot of work -- there is no need for a plethora of CTEs and subqueries:

- It replaces the code with the state name.
- It filters the data *before aggregation* (which is more efficient) for the two states you want.
- It assigns the sequence numbers to identify the best and worst counties.

You should probably be using a reference table to look up the state names.